# Xcode: Can't Install App on Apple Watch Simulator ("Will Install Watch App timed out")

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I try to run my first `WatchKit` `Swift` App in Watch Simulator in XCode, but it doesn't show in Watch simulator with this error message:

> Will Install Watch App timed out.

I have not found any error message like that on the internet and I don't know what to try. 
I am running `Xcode 7.3`, `Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.4`.
Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome on SO and please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). What is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: My question? : Why? How do I solve?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this happen as well. The simulator you're trying to install to has somehow become corrupt, reseting it doesn't fix the issue. You need to go into Xcode's Devices screen, delete the affected simulator and recreate an equivalent one.

Answer (score 3):

I found that these steps dramatically increase the chances of a successful install to nearly 100%:

1. Uninstall the app from both Simulators (iPhone and Watch).
2. Close all Simulator applications.
3. Run install from Xcode.

I hope that helps!